# how to check which safari version is installed on mac programmatically

Tags: safari, webkit, version

I can check the webkit version by /System/Library/Frameworks/Webkit/Resource/info.plist but how do I know if say safari 5 is installed there is no corresponding matrix telling the version of Webkit after which Safari 5 was shipped?

Comment: Note: macOS 10.13 path is /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to check webkit version essentially guaranteeing a safari version

```
 NSString* webkitPath = @"/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Resources/Info.plist";
 NSDictionary* webkitDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:webkitPath]; 
 NSString* versionString = [webkitDict valueForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
 int vs = [versionString intValue];
 int version = vs % 1000; // removing first digit which tells supported OS version number   
 // using this page for reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history
 if (version < 533) // safari 5 shipped with 533
```

Answer (score -1):

run safari and click on Safari - about Safari

Comment: i want to do it programmtically

Comment: I think the OP was referring to the version of WebKit, not Safari. I honestly have no idea...but what are you trying to do? Generally, I don't believe Apple updates the WebKit engine very often; they really only include major changes (even that that only *might* affect your rendering) with major version number changes. Not that they update Safari that often anyway.

Comment: app uses webview (webkit) so some features of that app require minimum safari version of 5